# Why can Format be used on the left side?

Tags: syntax

I am learning Mathematica in random order by reading its documentation. This approach is what I like most when learning new things.

Consider the following 2 cases.

Syntax A:

```
Format[Foo[x_,y_]]:=MatrixForm[{{x},{y}}]
Foo[1,2]
```

Syntax B:

```
Foo[x_,y_]:=Format[MatrixForm[{{x},{y}}]]
Foo[1,2]
```

My confusion is about why can we use `Format` on the left side? It seems to be counter intuitive as in most programming language, definition should be on the right side. Could you explain why?

Comment: I had trouble grasping "definitions" like these, too. Until I stopped thinking about them as "definitions" and started to see them as "replacement rules", i.e. telling the interpreter "if you see something that matches the pattern on the left, replace it with that stuff on the right side of the :=". Then it started making sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two definitions are not the same... it changes what kind of definition is associated with the symbols.

Consider the following:

#### Syntax 1:

```
ClearAll@Foo
Foo[x_, y_] := Format[MatrixForm[{{x},{y}}]]
DownValues@Foo
```

[image]

```
FormatValues@Foo
(* {} *)
```

#### Syntax 2:

```
ClearAll@Bar
Format[Bar[x_, y_]] := MatrixForm[{{x}, {y}}]
DownValues@Bar
(* {} *)

FormatValues@Bar
```

[image]

---

In the first case, the formatting rules are applied as `DownValues` to the function, which affects evaluation, whereas in the second case, the rules are associated with `FormatValues`. Syntax 2 is a better option if all you want to do is to change the appearance/formatting/presentation. However, *Mathematica* staying true to its principle of "everything is an expression", will allow you to define your function as in syntax 1.

Comment: I must also note that `Format[foo]` by itself does nothing and just returns the input, thus syntax 1 is also pointless from the point of doing what the OP intended.

Comment: Probably also worth mentioning that the output given by `FormatValues[Bar]` is actually displayed *according to those same `FormatValues`*, so the result may be a little misleading. Overall I don't really find `Format` all that useful. Definitions on `MakeBoxes` are much more versatile and less prone to unexpected problems (e.g. `FormatValues`-`MakeBoxes` continuous loop when one uses boxes in the `FormatValues` definitions). It seems to be a remnant from before the box language was introduced.